# How do I play videos in my website?r

Tags: codeigniter

The videos I want to play are in my computer. I have read the forums and guides and I only found guides that lets you play videos uploaded in a video hosting site like JW player and Kaltura. Is there a way to play videos coming directly from my computer? For example by using the path of the file not the link of the uploaded file in the video hosting site. Btw I'm making a youtube like website. 
This is my view:

```
      <body>
    <div id="container">

        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <div id="body">


           <div id="div2">
            <a href='<?php echo base_url()."main/search"; ?>'>Search!</a>
            <br>

            <a href='<?php echo base_url()."main/upload"; ?>'>Upload!</a>




                 <?php echo "<br>"; ?>
                 <a href='<?php echo base_url()."main/myAccount"; ?>'>Edit my Account!</a>
            <?php echo "<br>"; ?>


            <a href='<?php echo base_url()."main/logout" ?>'>Logout</a>
        </div>
        <div id ="searchBox">

       <video width="320" height="240" controls  >
       <source src="videos\53e38a25e298a.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       <source src="video\videos\53e38a25e298a.ogg" type="video/ogg">
       Your browser does not support the video tag.
       </video>


       </div>
       </div>
        <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds</p>
      </div>
     </body>
```

I'm trying to play a video (specific location for now) from my computer. But it won't play and it just show the player and play button and progress bar.

Update: I'm currently using xampp and codeigniter as the framework. 
I tried creating a single webpage placed in my Desktop using the code above and placed the video in my Desktop and it worked. But when I am using codeigniter it does not play. I've tried putting the video clips inside my view folder but still it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem, it seems that the path is indeed incorrect. The correct path is localhost/video/videos/53e38a25e298a.mp4

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into HTML5 Video, you can play videos in a similar way to how you would usually add an image from your computer into a website.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: I've tried this, but when I use google chrome it just shows a blank box with play icon and progress bar. But when I use internet explorer there's an error that says invalid source. I don't know whats the problem.

Comment: check your url paths to the videos—it looks like they are both different (one is videos\thevideo.mp4, and one is videos\video\thevideo.mp4)

Also use / instead of \ for the urls

Comment: It would seem that the URL's are wrong, or possibly the video encoding is a problem

Comment: I've also tried putting the exact location file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/video/videos/53e38a25e298a.mp4
but it wont still work.

Comment: I've solved the problem, it seems that the path is indeed incorrect. The correct path is http://localhost/video/videos/53e38a25e298a.mp4

How do I mark this question solved?

Comment: You can click answer Answer Your Own Question (below comments and other answers) and then click the check-box to set it as accepted answer